# Yum install / update not working inside docker images but working otherwise from the centos machine

Tags: docker, centos, nameservers

I am able to yum install, or yum update from the server, but when trying to do same (as specified in the Dockerfile) inside a docker container, it fails stating the following common error :
 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

```
     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/7/x86_64
```

my Docker file is a simple :

```
FROM centos:centos7
RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf
RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolv.conf
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install epel-release; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python-pip; yum clean all
```

I have tried various things like adding ip_resolve=4 in /etc/yum.conf, or addinf 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4 to /etc/resolv.conf and other methods, in vain.

here's the docker info :

```
Containers: 28
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 28
Images: 144
Server Version: 1.13.0

docker-compose version 1.10.1, build b252738
docker-py version: 2.0.2
CPython version: 2.7.5
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

Please help. I am only running things under a VPN, no proxy.

machine is an AMI : 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64. 
Need I add it's IP anywhere insde docker container? Please help.

TIA!

Comment: can you try again, but grouping all your commands in only one RUN?  See the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: oh, holy! how's that possible, I think it has worked? but.....howwww?let it run it full now though :D not that fast on the keyboard.

Comment: Hey, it worked, but how, what is the reason? this happens if I deploy on the server, whereas separate RUN commands hold good when I run on local. Please explain to me.

Comment: Using apt-get update alone in a RUN statement causes caching issues and subsequent apt-get install instructions fail. This might be the reason ?

Comment: You used `yum` and not `apt-get`.

Comment: I quoted the Docker Best Practices, I mean apt-get update and yum update are one and the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to directory: /etc/yum.repos.d/

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
```

And then run following commands

```
sudo sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sudo sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
sudo yum update -y
```

This will fix the yum update and install issues.